# React - Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InfoGridProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hrnzga?file=App.tsx,DisplayData.tsx)

I'm just trying to create a simple app where I pass data to a component and then display that data

So I have the data which is an array of objects I'm passing into the component `DisplayData`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import DisplayData from './DisplayData';
import './style.css';

export interface InfoGridProps {
  title: string;
  text: string;
}

const InfoGrid: InfoGridProps[] = [
  {
    title: 'Title 1',
    text: 'Type 1 Type 1 Type 1 Type 1 Type 1',
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 2',
    text: 'Type 2 Type 2 Type 2 Type 2 Type 2 Type 2 Type 2 Type 2 ',
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 3',
    text: 'Type 3 Type 3 Type 3 Type 3 ',
  },
];

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <DisplayData data={InfoGrid} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And then in the component I want to just loop through that data and displat it

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { FC } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export interface InfoGridProps {
  title: string;
  text: string;
}

export const DisplayData: FC<InfoGridProps[]> = (data) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div>
          <h1>{item.title}</h1>
          <p>{item.text}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DisplayData;
```

but here `<DisplayData data={InfoGrid} />` it says

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InfoGridProps'.
```

How can I get this simple app to work and display the data passed in

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct, in that you don't have `data` on your InfoGridProps type, which is what you've declared your `DisplayData` component to be.

I believe the correct way to type this is in `DisplayData` is to declare a type, and reference your `data` property as an array of that type:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { FC } from 'react'
import './style.css'

export interface InfoGridProps {
    data: InfoGridType[]
}

export type InfoGridType = {
    title: string
    text: string
}

export const DisplayData: FC<InfoGridProps[]> = (data) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((item) => (
                <div>
                    <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                    <p>{item.text}</p>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default DisplayData
```